# Complex values for a supposed real integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have an integral for which I have checked that it is supposed to be real but there some values of `zm` which gives a complex value.

First I checked the validity range of `func1` and `func2`,

```
ContourPlot[func1[z, zm, 9.30685, -15.5, 10], {z, 0, 9.30685}, {zm, 2, 14}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"z", "zm"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20], ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming
ContourPlot[func2[z, zm, 9.30685, 10], {z, 9.30685, 14}, {zm, 2, 14}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"z", "zm"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20], ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: func1]
[image: func2]

Below you will see that `zm~13.12...` and `zl=9.30685` so based on the contour plot, the function should be real numbers for the range specified.

Now here is my code,

```
d = 3;
ag = 20;
pg = 20;
wp = 100;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
func1[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Rationalize[FullSimplify[zm^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z, zh] zm^(2 d) - f[zm, zh] z^(2 d)]) - zl^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zl^(2 d) - (f[zl, zh] z^(2 d))/(f[zl, zh] + \[Sigma]^2))])], 0]
func2[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Rationalize[FullSimplify[zm^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z, zh] zm^(2 d) - f[zm, zh] z^(2 d)])], 0]
Sdiff1[zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[func1[z, zm, zl, \[Sigma], zh], {z, 10^-6, zl}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp] - 1/zl^(d - 1)
Sdiff2[zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[func2[z, zm, zl, zh], {z, zl, zm}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]
Sdiff[zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Sdiff1[zm, zl, \[Sigma], zh] + Sdiff2[zm, zl, zh]
```

I want to find the root of `Sdiff[zm,zl,\[Sigma],zh]=0`, so

```
Plot[Sdiff[zm, 0.930685, -1.55, 1], {zm, 1.31, 1.314}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming
Plot[Sdiff[zm, 9.30685, -15.5, 10], {zm, 13.1, 13.14}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: root1]
[image: root10]

I have plotted `Sdiff[zm,zl,\[Sigma],zh]` for different values, i.e. scale everything by factors of 10 (In this case I showed two different cases, `zh=1` and `zh=10`). As you can see there are complex values at some points which is very weird. This will affect how I find the root using `FindRoot`, for example

```
In[311]:= Sdiff[1.3122, 0.930685, -1.55, 1]

During evaluation of In[311]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in z near {z} = {1.10524401558531152310428738847291229469593603918764874985616942995484548973267025261496827751468857732080682244020164489570106785806413041234318401687*10^-6}. NIntegrate obtained -0.0953680951680931834745123674416812697318528782917380282484631277114279966108197976780600049228239456971990308722276004495808778188013233959933376197893 and 5.85518219686336069826959647527731082173980350941567052572749792113897389621195362705030451018833409494062810446414117340960083869273350500071564734243`150.*^-6 for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[311]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[311]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in z near {z} = {1.31219999996483775815022710925413900325446196741877373671252134559465310956494433552531673372086271474655712701563166561726401758962888297501592615831}. NIntegrate obtained 1.20335539716039122886908985026362661137726264579696310786318485276473000853231349656943135755073685036993548318482112178431183944472080815293312408373-2.98666309015455056925534269794783240056722422689357295577995834953594171518743926959095013943264159192680423190751058648637852902332826307958023336608*10^-8 I and 9.852591478099224742584715514655146848865875888877501022195950834394971266735884212697416425973180150042925051691217796179500572518840194547309207848`150.*^-8 for the integral and error estimates.

Out[311]= -0.0465144 - 2.98666*10^-8 I
```

```
In[316]:= 
FindRoot[Sdiff[zm, 0.930685, -1.55, 1] == 0, {zm, 
   1.313}] // AbsoluteTiming

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in z near {z} = {1.43628442733304049176237159421375406043675406787164837826181212170174294734144693316126775482870488514544158898529087874593892511596377848099164854596*10^-6}. NIntegrate obtained -0.0953677430126576890317804757035965852145657587652392085970936658759314126174898801398971900787493739043444088160327727805498519290223977816445364470503 and 2.89397313756015414359427380459096848107793820089910650435934688803685220569080408374145792659908259535152922600074117123194677145733427270103524166053`150.*^-6 for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in z near {z} = {1.31299999996476393815843577120175756096583203717702249833126334557685736161243282560190392580959562320605806579767154678758445722585164366254519505445}. NIntegrate obtained 1.24209549585833258515400729015185658085179856431970135575634837182003541211813883750840953454444322107739595395976933113881528509394769347545102038392-1.11260715736832754271226365950881587154788934169698566310114610778037210620400003096207658071042571105498101884905957622359883099514289681467968087977*10^-7 I and 9.11306124954966805954714643395838397126221015795969449969272935181145135202368019974986545127461924277936248514998091680891708387436445255181327286198`150.*^-8 for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in z near {z} = {1.43628442733304049176237159421375406043675406787164837826181212170174294734144693316126775482870488514544158898529087874593892511596377848099164854596*10^-6}. NIntegrate obtained -0.0953677430126576890317804757035965852145657587652392085970936658759314126174898801398971900787493739043444088160327727805498519290223977816445364470503 and 2.89397313756015414359427380459096848107793820089910650435934688803685220569080408374145792659908259535152922600074117123194677145733427270103524166053`150.*^-6 for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[316]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ncvb will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[316]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::slwcon will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand func2[z,1.31311 -8.39439*10^-6 I,0.930685,1] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.313106823851375892786563781555742025375366210937500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-8.39438812464856821027488209541189689844031818211078643798828125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*10^-6 I,1.31310682385137589278656378154532196282846108303459917393652031300261052080212042327483089465064104398127251947970448226866065749184806172138611881869-8.39438812464856821027488209518317028336138899066660076766073388076349356073810504462990043049957127732694718006373758881957959364026202385510465424045*10^-6 I}}.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand func2[z,1.31311 -8.43138*10^-6 I,0.930685,1] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.313106794078247929746794397942721843719482421875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-8.43138406127335189024427086756929838884389027953147888183593750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*10^-6 I,1.31310679407824792974679439793230178198382245897726121707531775353358197619357632018964367708580121668400692114874349854204266096059225964967595336693-8.43138406127335189024427086733956372466951666984520735049820226690615498627879851667470323522444300010977212779156432486485196065538859756075619294786*10^-6 I}}.

During evaluation of In[316]:= NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand func2[z,1.31311 -8.43138*10^-6 I,0.930685,1] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{1.313106794096682072847670497139915823936462402343750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-8.43137899897577064174235966786952189977455418556928634643554687500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*10^-6 I,1.31310679409668207284767049712949576220030015397972888398459406527352356028334368642572578628765041006633065497395603175327088345565398183827797449243-8.43137899897577064174235966763978737353545031654624029810073943077125217704951179703277710408782099359913267973633997017398860967033749757892941962606*10^-6 I}}.

During evaluation of In[316]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumri will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[316]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Out[316]= {18.7782, {zm -> 1.31311 - 8.43138*10^-6 I}}
```

It spits out complex values, which I do not know why.

Also, I still do not understand how `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal`, and `WorkingPrecision` play any role in these situations after reading through many other questions here in MSE. There some who said to make the numbers exact and use `Rationalize` & `FullSimplify`, use higher `WorkingPrecision`, etc. None of it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

d = 3;
ag = 20;
pg = 20;
wp = 100;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) function inputs prior to the calculation rather than rationalizing the end result of an inexact calculation. For performance reasons eliminate simplification except that which occurs naturally from the use of exact numbers. Use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to localize the temporary variables.

```
func1[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, 
   zh_?NumericQ] :=
  Module[{zr, zmr, zlr, σr, zhr},
   {zr, zmr, zlr, σr, zhr} = 
    Rationalize[{z, zm, zl, σ, zh}, 0];
   zmr^d/(zr^d Sqrt[f[zr, zhr] zmr^(2 d) - f[zmr, zhr] zr^(2 d)]) - 
    zlr^d/(zr^d Sqrt[
        f[zr, 
          zhr] (zlr^(2 d) - (f[zlr, zhr] zr^(2 d))/(f[zlr, 
               zhr] + σr^2))])];

func2[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
  Module[{zr, zmr, zlr, zhr},
   {zr, zmr, zlr, zhr} = Rationalize[{z, zm, zl, zh}, 0];
   zmr^d/(zr^d Sqrt[f[zr, zhr] zmr^(2 d) - f[zmr, zhr] zr^(2 d)])];

Sdiff1[zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zlr = Rationalize[zl, 0]},
  NIntegrate[func1[z, zm, zlr, σ, zh], {z, 10^-6, zlr}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp] - 
   1/zlr^(d - 1)]

Sdiff2[zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zlr, zmr},
  {zlr, zmr} = Rationalize[{zl, zm}, 0];
  NIntegrate[func2[z, zmr, zlr, zh], {z, zlr, zmr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, 
   PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]]

Sdiff[zm_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 Sdiff1[zm, zl, σ, zh] + Sdiff2[zm, zl, zh]
```

Test case,

```
Sdiff[1.3122, 0.930685, -1.55, 1] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {7.41299, \
-0.046510430706799189085784355939930933139694434574566957872349257327957297540\
0788205351038711701552046} *)
```

However, if the values of `{ag, pg, wp}` are only trying to avoid complex-valued results,

```
{ag = 10, pg = 10, wp = 20};

Sdiff[1.3122, 0.930685, -1.55, 1] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.18131, -0.04651043070679918730} *)
```

Plots

```
Plot[Sdiff[zm, 0.930685, -1.55, 1], {zm, 1.31, 1.314}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sdiff[zm, 9.30685, -15.5, 10], {zm, 13.1, 13.14}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we need to use `Module` here? Also, can you give a little bit more example for `Module`? The documentation for it contains only one example, did not quite get it.

Comment: In each case there are several temporary variables used whose names could **potentially** conflict with names in the `Global` namespace. `Module` localizes the temporary variables to eliminate any potential naming conflicts. For additional examples search this site (`Search on Mathematica ...`) for `Module`.

Comment: It worked, but do you know what exactly caused the complex values to arise? In the plot there are missing lines, i.e. no real solution.

Comment: With your definitions machine precision inputs are fed into a complicated calculation that causes loss of precision. Sometimes, the loss of precision will cause one or more of the arguments to `Sqrt` to be negative and give rise to complex numbers. Rationalizing the final imprecise result of a calculation cannot create precision. However, by rationalizing the input prior to the calculation, the complicated calculation is exact and there is no loss of precision.

Comment: Big thanks for a very informative and straight answer!